# Not able to receive and forward remote request using Charles Web Proxy as a Reverse Proxy

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, wireshark, charles-proxy

I am trying to capture an old application that didn't honour the system's proxy setting. The only config I can change is the server IP address.

Capturing the packets with Wireshark. Without the Charles reverse proxy, I can see requests after the first three handshake requests.

[image: without reverse proxy]

With the reverse proxy, the connection stuck after the handshake requests.

[image: with reverse proxy]

I notice that when Charles received a request and connecting to somewhere but it will just stuck there:

[image: connecting]

Following is the config of the reverse proxy (Remote host removed):

[image: reverse proxy config]

Any help, solution and workarounds would be appreciated!

Comment: This could be because of two reasons I can think of. One is that the data is a TCP stream and not http protocol as such. Next possibility is that the application is using HTTPS certificate pinning and validating the hash of the certificate

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think it is not an HTTPS certificate pinning as the application connects to an IP address instead of a domain. Will check again with the TCP stream though. If TCP stream is the case, which direction should I go? Or is it technically not possible to capture and manipulate the packets? Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your app uses neither HTTP nor HTTPS. Studying screen shot of successful connection gives some details on protocol used:

- the first message after handhsake is originated by server contrary to common client-server approach, where client is responsible for sending query. This fact is enough to cross out HTTP and HTTPS.
- payload data isn't human-readable, so it's a binary protocol.
- based on PUSH flags, protocol is much more likely to be message-based rather than stream-based

So client establishes connection, immediately gets some command from server and replies it. Then communication continues. I can't guess exact protocol. Port number might be irrelevant, but even if it's not, there are [only few protocols](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=4321) using 4321 port by default. Anyway, it can always be custom private protocol.

I'm not familiar with Charles, but forwarding arbitrary TCP stream is probably covered by its [port forwarding](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/port-forwarding/) feature rather than reverse proxy. However, I don't really see any benefits in sending traffic through Charles in this case, capturing data on your PC should be enough to study details.

If you are looking for traffic manipulation, for arbitrary TCP stream it's not an easy task, but it must be possible. I'm not aware of suitable tools, quick googling shows lots of utils, but some of them looks applicable to text based stream only, so deeper study is required.

Answer (score 0):

### Reason for Failure

It may be because you are requesting a local IP address from a remote scope, which Charles proxy doesn't applies. For POS(Proof Of Statement), please refer to the below link

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/localhost-traffic-doesnt-appear-in-charles/

---

### Solution

So In order to solve the problem for the current scenario, use

> http://192.168.86.22.charlesproxy.com/

Note: The url that you request will only be proxied properly by Charles not any other proxy services.